# Playing an HDHomeRun stream on a Tizen.NET Xamarin App

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying to play a HDHomeRun Connect Video source from a url in the following format: http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/auto/v4.1. This video source is an MPEG2 video encoding and AC3 audio encoding.

I've tried using the Samsung Tizen.TV .NET sample with the following source but the video never plays.

```
_player = new Tizen.Multimedia.Player();

var mediaSource = new Multimedia.MediaUriSource(uri);
_player.SetSource(mediaSource);

var display = new Multimedia.Display(Window.Instance);   
_player.Display = display;
await _player.PrepareAsync();
```

The player state gets stuck in preparing, and the `await _player.PrepareAsync()` call never finishes. It is worth noting that I'm using the Tizen Samsung TV Emulator. Do I need to transcode the stream from the HDHomeRun to be playable? Are there any other measures I might be missing for the Video to play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, the Display property of the player wasn't being set correctly. The property that worked for me (found from investigating the [JuvoPlayer code](https://github.com/SamsungDForum/JuvoPlayer) was this:

```
        var display = new Multimedia.Display(((FormsApplication)Forms.Context).MainWindow);

        _player.Display = display;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are to develop a Tizen .NET application, please be aware of which UI framework your project is targetted for among 3 different types: **Xamarin.Forms**, **(pure) ElmSharp**, and **Tizen.NUI**.

Unless your project is based on the Tizen.NUI framework, you shouldn't use `Tizen.NUI.Window.Instance` and types in `Tizen.NUI` namespace in any case. Instead, you will have to use types of `ElmSharp` or `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Tizen` namespace for platform-specific code in your application.

Since the internal implementation of Xamarin.Forms for Tizen is based on ElmSharp, `FormsApplication.MainWindow` will return a `ElmSharp.Window` instance which can be used to instantiate a `Tizen.Multimedia.Display` object. That's why the code in your answer worked.